# Is an implicit property type same with an explicit property type?

Tags: android, oop, kotlin, design-principles

The following Code A is from Kotlin-for-Android-Developers. The Code B is written by me.

Do these two different blocks of code function the same way?

**Code A**

```
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ToolbarManager {

    override val toolbar by lazy { find<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar) }

    ...    
}
```

**Code B**

```
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ToolbarManager {

    override val toolbar: Toolbar by lazy { find<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar) }

    ...    
}
```

Comment: Test it and see :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the **structure** point of view, they are the same. the Kotlin compiler will emits the same java byte code of the source code both likes as below:

```
private final Lazy<Toolbar> toolbarProvider = lazy(()-> find(R.id.toolbar));

public Toolbar getToolbar(){
       return toolbarProvider.getValue();
}
```

the property type is optional in *code B* above, but it is useful when programming by interface rather than implementation [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), if the implementation was changed the only one need to change is where it is instantiated, since the usage of the `toolbar` can't access the features declared by its sub-classes at all. for example:

```
//declare as abstract supertype ---v
override val toolbar: AbstractToolbar by lazy { find<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar) }
//                                                    ^
//when implementation was changed only need to change here.
//e.g:change the `Toolbar` to other subtype of AbstractToolbar: find<MiniToolbar>()
```

---

From the **compiler** point of view, they are different. Since the compiler will infer the actual property type in the *code A* at compile-time, for example:

```
//                     v--- the property type `Toolbar` is inferred at compile-time
override val toolbar/*:Toolbar*/ by lazy { find<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar) }
```

[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle